# How can I make rain in blender?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles

I want to make plain rain in blender, but the most recent attempt in cycles resulted in the denoiser eating it :P Is my only option no denoising, EEVEE, or a purely compositing effect? Have somewhat considered rendering the rain in a separate layer, but rather not re-invent the wheel if the answer's already out there.

Comment: Hello, maybe give some details about what you want to achieve, is it realistic rain, cartoony, are you supposed to see puddles on the ground, splashes, etc? There are several tutorials on this topic on youtube, haven't you found one that works?

Comment: Quick fix: Put the rain on a separate render layer and don't denoise that.

Comment: Realistic rain on a city street. I had manually created mesh puddles. Have not had time to look on youtube, mainly. Originally had planned a misty rain that shows up mostly in front of street lamps, but the lamps are very close together, so maybe just kind of a drippy rain is better. Untextured volumetrics have been unsatisfactory: too uniform. Want streaks.

Comment: Have looked on youtube, and did find some helpful info :) One thing that helped alot was making the raindrop surface rougher.